# Ractive computed template functions leaking?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, ractivejs

Before i go on i should say that i'm not very comfortable with the chrome debugger, but i've hit a performance problem and chrome seems to mirror it in it's timeline.

I've got two components. One `Parent` and one `Child`. `Parent`s template loops over an array of variables called `events` and passes `event={{.}}` to a `Child`. For each `Child` created the child executes `{{moment().format("HH:mm:ss")}}`. `Parent` then replaces the entire `events` array with a new array, and `{{moment().format("HH:mm:ss")}}` gets executed X times again.

If you start chrome and use the developer tools *Timeline* function you can press the small *Record* button and then spam the `Next page` button for a while(I did it until ~15% of the buffer was filled) then after ~15% of data you can press the garbage button(GC), wait a few seconds and stop recording.

Now on the result you'll see where you ran the GC by looking at where the `Listeners` is going straight down. However the nodes and memory allocation are still high.

In my real application the computations are more and heavier and the memory gets filled real quick which makes the page slow and sluggish.

Here's the fiddle so you can try it:

http://jsfiddle.net/PCcqJ/104/

**EDIT**:

After some more debugging i found out that if i removed `event={{.}}` from the `Item` there was no longer an infinite amount of nodes being created. I have a list which shows 7 items per page. Then when i press "Next Page" 7(always 7) new items are displayed. See the code:

```
{{#each dates}}
  {{#each itemsForDate(.)}}
    <div class="item">
      <Item data={{.}} />
    </div>
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

It seems like what i pass to the `Item` as `data` isn't garbage collected on teardown for some reason, even though i've removed my own references to the data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not quite sure what, in specifics, the problem is but I managed to determine that it had to do with moment js and ractive templates. Maybe something with references.

As soon as I moved my moment calls out of the template and into the component javascript the memory leaks disappeared. Now it's super smooth.

The bottom line for me: Don't use moment.js in Reactive templates.
Reason: Unknown for me at the moment and I'm afraid I don't have time to research.

Comment: Also taking a closer look at the example not using moment there seems to be some initial "memory leak" when using ractive, but i'm not sure if it's actually a leak. However it's so small it's probably negligible